# Can not fetch email from Facebook in Swift

Tags: swift, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

EDIT: The problem with this question is a bit silly. As in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33532312/2152616) the problem is that I have not given the parameters which I want.

I can not get through with it anymore :) What can be the problem?

```
    func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("fetched user: \(result)")
            let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
            print("User Name is: \(userName)")
            let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
            print("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
}
```

I call the function like that:

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!,
    didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!,
    error: NSError!) {
        print("User Logged In")

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                // Do work
                returnUserData()
            }
        }
}
```

I get the error:

[image]

My problem is about the **fatal error**. However, I am kindly waiting for the comments on 2nd and 3rd lines of the output. Because, I get this output every time but the app runs correctly.

Comment: Your fields parameter is nil which as your error message says "as of Graph API v 2.4 GET requests for me should contain an explicit fields parameter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the parameters for the request.

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email"])
```